# Mount NFSv3 From Windows Server 2019

Tags: linux, mount, nfs, windows-server-2019

I have enabled NFS sharing on windows server 2019 using NFS version 3.
I have disabled both NFS ver 2 and NFS ver 4 via powershell:

```
Set-NfsServerConfiguration -EnableNfsv2 $False -EnableNfsv4 $False -EnableNfsv3 $True
```

In my CentOS 7, I tried to mount NFS using the following command:

```
mount -t nfs -o vers=3 192.168.0.4:/NFS /home4
```

but getting an error:

```
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

May I know what did I miss?

Comment: Verify what you did against [this article](https://msftwebcast.com/2020/02/how-to-configure-nfs-share-in-windows-server-2019.html), and especially as regarding permissions.

Comment: I have given full access to root and I am mounting via root user. Please see attached screenshot link:-
https://prnt.sc/26v6vq3

I have tried to enable NSFv4 and I am able to mount using NSFv4 but not NSFv3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Microsoft article
[Network File System overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/nfs/nfs-overview),
Windows Server 2019 only supports NFSv4.1 -
it doesn't support NFSv3.

[image]